# client.run("TOKEN") blocking issue (python & discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I know that client.run("TOKEN") blocks off any code following it...I'm trying to have my program print a message (in my case when a Nike product restocks), and then keep running and print another one when it picks up something again. How can I close/shut off my client.run("TOKEN") command so that my program can keep running?

```
else:
            print("NO RESTOCK FOUND...STILL MONITORING")

            client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

            channel = client.get_channel(ABCDEFG)
            await channel.send("NO RESTOCK FOUND...STILL MONITORING")

            client.run("TOKEN")

            time.sleep(0.5)

            client.close()
```

Comment: Why do you want to run the client for 0.5 seconds and then close it? Also, please provide some context: is the code you wrote here inside an `async` function?

Comment: I am creating a Nike product monitor in Python that checks for restocks on certain shoes.  Essentially, without worrying about discord bots and sending the sizes in stock to a specific channel, I can monitor a product page on Nike and it will pick up sizes that have restocked.  All I want to do is to send a message to a discord channel when that happens, instead of having the sizes display in Terminal.  I'm pretty new to discord.py, but I can't imagine that sending a string of text when my monitor/code picks up a restock on Nike is too hard.

Comment: Also, I know when you write client.run("TOKEN"), it blocks the code afterwards.  How can I send a message to a specific channel, but then keep my monitor running?

Comment: So do you just want a non-blocking version of `client.run()`?

Comment: Yeah, and also some advice on how to send a message to a channel.  I'm seeing a lot of tutorials on sending messages on command (eg. !ping returns pong) but I want to send a message of the sizes of when my monitor picks them up.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: A tip, if u want to respond to the user in the same chat instead of doing 

channel = client.get_channel(ABCDEFG)
            await channel.send("NO RESTOCK FOUND...STILL MONITORING")

you can just do await ctx.send("the message") and make sure in the function u pass the argument "ctx"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `client.run()`, you can use `await client.start()`, which does not block the code.

```py
import asyncio

async def client_start():
    await client.start('token.goes.here')
```

You can then call `await client.start()` in your function.

---

To send a message use `message.channel.send('Message')` or `ctx.send('Message')`, depending on if you are using an event or command.

Answer (score 0):

i have a bot that require to send a signals every random time and **some times i need to send messages bellow the client.run** line , so i couldn't found any solution , the best way i found to send a messages in any place in the code in any time like this , using the basic URL request method :

all you need to change in this code is :

1/ line no 2 ( **your channel id** )

2/ line no 4 ( **your channel Token** ) or  ( **Bot Token** if trying to send as bot )

3/ the_message = '**any message you want to send**'

```
import requests
the_url = 'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/your_channel_id/messages'


def send(the_message):
    TOKEN = 'Your_Bot_Token'
    header = {
        'authorization': f'Bot {TOKEN}',
    }

    payload = {
        'content': f'{the_message}',

        'author': {
            'pinned': True
        }
    }
    requests.post(the_url, data=payload, headers=header)


######### Calling the Function to send a message in any place in the code ^_^ #########

send(the_message='Hola')
```

you can call send function in any place in the code ^_^ .

Answer (score -2):

You could import Threading and use the class Thread, basically make a function like:

```
def runClient():
    client.run("TOKEN")
```

and in that part that u want the client.run("TOKEN") to be run just do this:
threading.Thread(target=runClient).start()
this will create a thread that will run that function and will keep doing the rest after that function, hope this helps!!

Comment: I put the function above as runClient, and then the following: `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

            @client.event
            async def on_ready():
                print("Nike Monitor is Online")


            threading.Thread(target=runClient).start()` however I'm getting an error saying client is not defined/found

Comment: Also, I apologize about formatting, I'm new to StackOverflow.

Comment: "
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")
"
this would be the client, try to pass the client to that function

Comment: change the thread to this :
threading.Thread(target=runClient, args=(client,)).start()  and add an argument to the function called client aswell, btw u need to leave the "," in the args parameter on the thread because it is a tuple !!

Comment: OK I get the second comment but wdym by passing the client to the function? How would I re-write that?

Comment: this function will be outside any aync function !! 
def runClient(client):
    client.run("TOKEN")
just like this

Comment: Here's what I have (sorry -- I'm new to threading and async stuff).  At the top of my program I have def runClient(client): client.run("token"), and then later in my while True loop that monitors a nike product, I have client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

            @client.event
            async def on_ready():
                print("Nike Monitor is Online")
                
            threading.Thread(target=runClient, args=(client,)).start().  I'm getting a new error that says RuntimeError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread.

Comment: still getting this error: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread...any ideas?