# discord one script run multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Friends, I am making a discord script using python I have to run this script multiple times with different parameters, I am trying that with os, threading, multiprocessing. when I am trying with this library that works only for first data Then it stuck, My code is below, please advise me.

> note:- I am login as a user.

**CSV file demo**

```
auth-token1,channel-id1-1,channelid1-2
auth-token2,channel-id2-1,channelid2-2
...
...
```

**main.py**

```
import os
import csv
from time import sleep
import threading
import multiprocessing
rows = []
with open('data.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    # creating a csv reader object
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    # extracting each data row one by one
    for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row)

for _ in rows:
    li = _[1:]
    cmd = _[0]
    for i in li:
        cmd = cmd+" "+str(i)
    print(f'python3 script.py {cmd}')
    os.system(f'python3 script.py {cmd}')
    sleep(10)
```

**script.py**

```
import time
import os
import sys
from time import sleep
import os
from discord import Permissions, message
import discord
import logging
import sys

argumentList = sys.argv
print(argumentList[1:])
TOKEN_AUTH = argumentList[1]
os.environ['TZ'] = 'Asia/Kolkata'
time.tzset()

logging.basicConfig(handlers=[logging.FileHandler(filename="./discord.txt",
                                                encoding='utf-8', mode='a+')],
                    format="%(asctime)s %(name)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s",
                    datefmt="%F %A %T",
                    level=logging.INFO)

channel = None
client = discord.Client()
ids = argumentList[2:]
sleep_time = 121
message = "enter your message"


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global channel
    while True:
        for _ in ids:
            try:
                channel1 = client.get_channel(int(_))
                await channel1.send(message)
                logging.info('1')
                print('sleeping')
                sleep(sleep_time*60)
            except:
                client.run(TOKEN_AUTH, bot=False)

client.run(TOKEN_AUTH, bot=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is against Discord TOS to use bot=False otherwise known as a self bot (user)

All I will say is d.py is asynchronous and parts of your code are synchronous  which is blocking.

client.run() is also a blocking method which is why your main.py stops running after the first run. Everything you do, with discord bots, needs to be async and within the client loop.

I recommend you rethink exactly what you are trying to do and do something that is not breaking their Terms of Service.

Comment: I am trying to send msg `!d bump` that's working only by the user.

Comment: if you have any other solution?

Comment: I don't think many people are going to assist you with this, not even on the official d.py discord.

Comment: I am trying to trigger my server bot.

Comment: If you have a real bot then just use Tasks extension to schedule when to do things. DO NOT USE A SELF BOT (USER)

Answer (score 0):

The reason because you are using ( **client.run** ) , this method will block the lines after it .

if you want to send messages in any place in your code ,

check this solution ^_^ :

[client.run("TOKEN") blocking issue (python & discord.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62203617/client-runtoken-blocking-issue-python-discord-py/71983595#71983595)