# How to use discord.py asynchronously with another function

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py, web3py

I am trying to run this code in a way that runs the function background() at startup while also running client.run() to start a discord bot. How can I achieve this? In its current state, depending on which order I call the functions mentioned above, it only runs the first one, so in this case it only runs the discord bot because i called the function first...

````py
from hashlib import new
from re import I
from web3 import Web3
import sys, json, time, asyncio, threading
from logging import exception
import json
import time
import urllib3
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands

# set rpc
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("rpc goes here (i have hidden for this post)"))

# use https://github.com/Cog-Creators/Red-DiscordBot/issues/581 to solve SSL problems on Mac OS
# use "token" not "client secret" for discord bot
discord_token = ('discord secret here i have hidden for this post')
# init discord stuff
client = discord.Client()
# set bot command prefix
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$') #put your own prefix here


# take block data input, parse for new contract, then call discord function to broadcast
async def contractTx(txhash):
    # call when new block is found to get contract addy and send it to discord
    new_contract = web3.eth.get_transaction_receipt(txhash)
    global contract_address
    contract_address = new_contract['contractAddress']
    print(f"New contract deployed: {contract_address}")
    await new_contract_discord(contract_address=contract_address)



# runs on program startup
async def background():
    # set block index
    global block_index
    block_index = web3.eth.get_block_number()
    # start looping through blocks
    while True:
        if block_index != web3.eth.get_block_number():
            # new block, do the things
            # set current block to new block
            block_index = web3.eth.get_block_number()
            # check if transactions in new block contain new contract creation
            # if yes, send to main function
            print(f"NEW BLOCK: {block_index}")
            global transactions
            current_block = web3.eth.get_block(block_index, full_transactions=True)
            transactions = current_block.transactions
            for tx in transactions:
                if tx['to'] != None:
                    # is a contract creation tx, send to export function
                    task1 = asyncio.create_task(contractTx(tx['hash'].hex()))
        else:
            # still the same block, so wait a bit
            print("no new blocks")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot online") #will print "bot online" in the console when the bot is online

@client.event
async def new_contract_discord(ctx, contract_address):
    channel = client.get_channel(949889447938367531)
    await channel.send(f"new contract: {contract_address}")


# test command so you know how it works
# do $foo "string" and it responds with "string"
@client.command()
async def foo(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

# run the discord bot with the token
client.run(discord_token)

# run the background func
asyncio.run(background())```
````

Comment: asyncio has some method to add many functions to queue before starting loop which will execute them in the same time. Try [create_task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks) for first function and later `run()` for second function

Comment: @furas I did ``discordtask = asyncio.create_task(client.run(discord_token)) asyncio.run(background())`` and still only the first function runs, the second one does not

Comment: only `create_task(discord_token())` without `run()`. You could also try different order - `create_task(background())` and `client.run(discord_token)`

Comment: other idea (but not tested): use `@tasks.loop(count=1)` with `def background()` to start it after starting `discord` - doc [discord.ext.tasks – asyncio.Task helpers](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html). Other idea: run `await background()` in `on_ready()` and maybe use `asyncio.sleep(0.1)` in every loop in `while True` - this way it may go to other functions.

Comment: hey , i faced the same problem , check the solution here with simple url request you can send messages in any place in the code :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62203617/client-runtoken-blocking-issue-python-discord-py/71983595#71983595

Answer (score 2):

```
import threading
def A():
    while True:
        print("A")
def B():
    while True:
        print("B")
threading.Thread(target=A).start()
threading.Thread(target=B).start()
```

This will output ABABAB... So, the functions are running simultaneously.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @xDev120 I receive an error :
```set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread of the main interpreter

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:```

Comment: @JohnWarts It looks like your function wants to run on the main thread. You should see the async (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) and the threading (https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) documentation.